# how to insert data in a column of type RAW

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column of type RAW, by inserting an image, when I was working with H2 I used **READ_FILE** but in oracle I couldn't figure out how to do that. I tried to convert the image to base 64, and insert the given code but I get this error :

> Erreur SQL : ORA-01704: constante de chaîne trop longue 01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"

searching on the net I find that the sql quert is too long and that I should use plsql query, but this one doesn't work either.
can anyone help ??.
thank you in advance

Comment: In plsql you're limited to (I think) 32k to insert into raw. Can't you change the column to blob type? Raw is deprecated. If you can't, you might some problem trying to send that image to raw.

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the column type :(